# How do I disable a button using data bindings in Dart?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

In a response to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849068/how-do-i-set-the-disabled-property-of-a-button-using-dart-web-ui), that is more than a year old, I read about an easy way to disable a button using data binding in Dart (and polymer-dart).

My current code looks like this:

*html*:

```dart
...
<button id="btnPointDown" on-click="{{decrement}}" disabled="{{points == 0}}">\/</button>
...
```

*.dart*:

```dart
...
@published int points = 0;

void increment() {
  points++;
}

void decrement() {
  points--;
}
...
```

However Dart does not seem 'to be clever' about the disabled element anymore.

How do I use up-to-date Dart and Polymer to disable a button using data bindings (or if not possible programmatically)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Binding to the disabled attribute can be done like this:

```dart
<button ... disabled?="{{ points == 0 }}">Content</button>
```

This `?` is special syntax introduced by Polymer to support binding to this kind of boolean attributes.

This does not work:

```dart
<button ... disabled="{{ points == 0 }}">Content</button>
```

Because it would result in

```dart
<button ... disabled="false">Content</button>
```

which would still disable the button.

For **Polymer >= 1.0** the new syntax to use is:

```dart
<button ... disabled$="{{value}}">Content</button>
```

Note: `value` already has to be a boolean as Marco pointed out below. Otherwise you have to create a function that would return `points == 0`. See [Data Binding Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding) here and [Migration Guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#computed-properties) here for reference.

Regards,
Robert

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is this documented in the Polymer Docs somewhere?

Comment: Yes it is: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#conditional-attributes

Comment: unfortunately this does not seem to be working for 1.0 anymore

Answer (score 6):

for `polymer 1.0` I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31763221/2210287).

It should be: `<button ... disabled$="{{myTestFunction()}}">Content</button>`

FYI: I have **not** been able to use simple statements like `points == 0`, but instead I had to use a function, which returns a `boolean`.

Comment: Binding expressions are very limited in 1.x. Only property names, the not operator `!` and function calls are supported.