# How to declaratively bind pseudo-boolean attributes like disabled/checked to boolean values?

Tags: polymer

Is there an easy way to bind attributes like `disabled` or `checked` to true/false properties? Something like

`<button disabled="{{myBooleanProperty}}">Ok</button>`

doesn't work as desired. If myBooleanProperty is false, this sets `disabled="false"`, which is *true* as far as HTML is concerned.

Is there a filter expression that can hint to the binding parser that the attribute should be completely removed if the value is false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See conditional attributes:
http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#conditional-attributes

Example:

```
<button disabled?="{{myBooleanProperty}}">Ok</button>
```

will toggle `disabled` depending on the truthiness of `myBooleanProperty`.

Comment: Perfect! I just combed through that article yesterday in search of a solution, but somehow missed that part. Thanks.

Comment: 404 on that link.  Do you want to update it with [Data binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding)?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Polymer 1.0:

```
<button disabled$="{{myBooleanProperty}}">Ok</button>
```

See the docs on [data bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding).

Comment: this isn't working for me (Polymer 1.0) (everytime disabled)